# Are OWLAPI APIs thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, owl-api

I am interested to know whether APIs of OWLAPI are thread-safe. I am using OWLAPI version 5.1.10 in my project to interact with OWL ontology. I am planning to use OWLAPI functionalities like:

```
addAxiom(OWLOntology, OWLAxiom) method of OWLOntologyManager
getOWLObjectProperty() method of OWLDataFactory
applyChange() method of OWLOntologyManager
```

from multiple threads, however I am not sure if the changes to ontology will be consistent in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OWLDataFactory is thread safe.
OWLOntologyManager must be created with OWLManager.createConcurrentOWLOntologyManager() to be thread safe.